# Devart T4 Editor Supporting Additional Extensions

Tags: editor, t4, devart

Does anyone know if it is possible to associate the [Devart T4 Editor](http://www.devart.com/t4-editor) for Visual Studio add-in to additional file extensions. I am currently creating some custom [MVCScaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) T4 templates and their file extension is .t4 However, it looks like the Devart T4 Editor currently only is associated with .tt files. I know as a workaround that I can just rename my file until I am finished editing it, then rename back to run... But this is a pain when in an edit/debug cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the inquiry. We will add this extension in the nearest build.
This build will be available in several days.
**Update.** We have published [the new build](http://www.devart.com/t4-editor).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the quick response, looking forward to this.

Comment: I just downloaded the update and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Devart - i downloaded and installed the T4 editor extension into Visual Studio 2012, but cannot find the spot to add extensions - any pointers? If it matters have ReSharper 7 and VS version is 11 Update 4